# tmux force resize window

Tags: tmux

I usually connect to remote linux servers from a specific windows server (W1). On the Windows side, I use `putty` and on the linux side, I start `tmux`.

Occasionally, I have to use a different windows server (W2) and connect to the same `tmux` sessions.

**Problem:** If I had set a size for the `putty` windows on W1, then I can not exceed this size on W2. When I maximise the `putty` window, the extra space is unusable, filled with `~` characters.

Is there a way to "force" resize on W2, even if that means W1 will show only partial output ? Or a way to make W1 get disconnected from `tmux` session ?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

With `tmux list-client`, you can list all clients connected to tmux sessions. For instance:

```
$ tmux list-client
/dev/pts/6: 0 [25x80 xterm] (utf8)
/dev/pts/8: 0 [25x80 xterm] (utf8)
```

From this point, you can choose to detach a specified client, or all clients of a specified session. Say I want to detach everyone connected to session 0:

```
$ tmux detach-client -s 0
```

Then, you can attach the session so the size will be yours.

Actually, all that can be done with `tmux attach -d` (the `-d` option force all other clients to detach).

Comment: Cool !! "-d" is exactly what I wanted !!

Comment: Thanks, in my case it was `tmux detach-client -t /dev/pts/X` I was looking for.

Comment: a shortcut to the verbose 'list-client' is: `tmux ls`

Comment: matias, actually "tmux ls" is a shortcut for "list-sessions"

Comment: For `tmux attach -d`, you can use it from within the tmux session by doing `<c-b> :attach -d` or outside with `tmux attach -d -t <session_name>`

Answer (score 53):

It is not necessary to detach the other sessions. Use

```
<c-b>:resize-window -A
```

to grow the window to the largest connected session.

Other useful parameters to `resize-window` (`resizew`) are:

- `-a`: resize to the smallest session.
- `-U`, `-D`, `-L` and `-R`: adjust up, down, left or right, respectively. Can be followed by a number, determining how much to grow (`-D` and `-R`) or shrink (`-U` and `-L`).
- `-x <width>` and/or `-y <height>` set width and height to the given values.

Comment: Unknown command: resize-window

Comment: @onlinespending Same here, tmux 2.7, default centos stream 8

Comment: @Alexis yeah. I needed to update my tmux. I used linux brew since I don't have root access on my work machine

Answer (score 18):

if you are already in tmux then you can detach all other connections using `:detach-client -a`. It leaves your current session only. Consequently you won't have extra space is unusable, filled with `~` characters.

Comment: +1 ! This way, we do not have to exit and connect again !

Comment: Will this work very well on old ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS and with old TMUX Client. Thanks sir

Comment: @BenyaminLimanto , Yes , it will work with Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS having TMUX client ; My Question was itself asked much earlier in 2015 & the given solutions did work !

Answer (score 0):

If you use `xterm`,
then you can manually resize your `tmux` window on W2 by:

1. detach from the `tmux` session from W1 and W2,
2. type `resize` into your terminal on W2 and run it,
3. return to your session and the window should be resized.

(Suppose you did not enable automatic window resizing for `tmux`.)