# tmux: How to always resize all windows to maximum available size?

Tags: bash, command-line, tmux

I am running tmux 3.0a, and when I connect with a smaller resolution terminal, also the bigger terminal gets resized to the smaller.

This is well known (although I don't understand why they made this the default behaviour), and the solution is to `c-b c-: :resize-window -A` ([tmux force resize window](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/218815/tmux-force-resize-window/570015#570015), https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7814612/is-there-any-way-to-redraw-tmux-window-when-switching-smaller-monitor-to-bigger/61764869#61764869). Unfortunately, this needs to be done in every pane/window.

While there is this option `set-window-option -g aggressive-resize on`, it doesn't have any effect for me.

So: How to always resize all windows to maximum available size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apperently, `:resize-window -A` needs to be done in every window, but when it's done it's persisting (when you disconnect and reconnect with a smaller terminal it remembers to resize aggressively).

Thus, include in your `.bashrc` the following command:

`tmux resize-window -A`

This sets aggressive resize for that specific window, whenever you open a new window.

It remains unclear why it actually works, see the discussion in the comments. The problem is that the documentation of tmux is unclear and there are three options that influence resizing.

Another way to achieve proper resizing seems to be (for tmux >=3.1):

```
set -g window-size latest
setw -g aggressive-resize on
```

Comment: Just `set -g window-size largest` or `smallest` whichever you prefer, if you do `resize-window -A` you end up with it set to `manual` for that window and you will need to do it again every time you resize the terminal.

Comment: oh wow! I am still testing it, but this looks even better – You should make this an answer instead of a comment!

Comment: Sorry, I was too quick. `set -g window-size largest` sets the window-size to the largest window, and thus on the smaller one you only see half the content. So `tmux resize-window -A` is still the only way to have the right window size for all clients.

Comment: Just leave it at the default of `latest` and it will use the size of the client you used most recently, so it will change as soon as you type. There is no way for both clients to be the right size, one of them has to either too big or too small.

Comment: I don't really understand why `resize-window -A` would work for you, it just sets the size manually to the largest client. As soon as your current client becomes smaller than the largest attached, it will have the wrong size. A smaller client will still see only half the content.

Comment: That's not how -A works: https://mutelight.org/practical-tmux#section-5

Comment: No, that is the `aggressive-resize` option which is entire separate from `resize-window -A`. `aggressive-resize` has no effect after `resize-window -A` because at that point `window-size` is `manual`.

Comment: If you run `resize-window -A` in a window and attach the session from two different terminals the window will stay a fixed size (the size of the largest attached client when you ran `resize-window -A`), so I don't know what you are doing that means it is always the right size. Are you just running it again whenever you resize the terminal? Anyway it doesn't really matter, if it works for you. But if you are using tmux 3.1 then `window-size latest` seems like it would be better because then tmux will resize automatically as soon as you interact with a client.

Comment: Thanks a lot @NicholasMarriott for your continued explanations. I am still trying to make sense of it. Looking at the man page I find these three commands/settings:

Comment: 1) ```tmux      resize-window [-aADLRU] [-t target-window] [-x width] [-y height] [adjustment]```
                   (alias: resizew)
             Resize a window, up, down, left or right by adjustment with -U, -D, -L or -R, or to an absolute size with -x or -y.  The adjustment is given in lines or cells (the default is 1).  -A sets the size of the largest
             session containing the window; -a the size of the smallest.  This command will automatically set window-size to manual in the window options.

Comment: 2) `aggressive-resize [on | off]`
             Aggressively resize the chosen window.  This means that tmux will resize the window to the size of the smallest or largest session (see the window-size option) for which it is the current window, rather than the
             session to which it is attached.  The window may resize when the current window is changed on another session; this option is good for full-screen programs which support SIGWINCH and poor for interactive programs
             such as shells.

Comment: 3)  `window-size largest | smallest | manual`
             Configure how tmux determines the window size.  If set to largest, the size of the largest attached session is used; if smallest, the size of the smallest.  If manual, the size of a new window is set from the
             default-size option and windows are resized automatically.  See also the resize-window command and the aggressive-resize option. (That's from the 3.2 man page)

Comment: 3) `window-size largest | smallest | manual | latest`
             Configure how tmux determines the window size.  If set to largest, the size of the largest attached session is used;
             if smallest, the size of the smallest.  If manual, the size
             of a new window is set from the default-size option and windows are resized automatically.  With latest, tmux uses the size of the client that had the most recent activity. See also the resize-window command and the aggressive-resize option.  (From https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tmux.1.html, unknown version)

Comment: It's unclear to me how `window-size`, `resize-window` and `aggressive-resize` interact with each other. If I interpret the doc correctly `manual` leads to "windows are resized automatically", which would be the desired behaviour. Thus maybe `resize-window -A` works because it sets the window-size option to manual?

Comment: Despite not being in the man page of 3.2, `latest` still seems to be a valid option. The combination of `aggressive-resize on` and `window-size latest` works also very well for me.

Comment: The text for `manual` is unclear, I think perhaps I intended that it say "*not* resized automatically" there. If you use `manual` tmux will not resize windows unless asked to (via `resize-window`). If you use `resize-window`, tmux will set `manual` itself (compare `show-options` in the window before and after `resize-window`). Manual sizing is really intended as an option for people with specific size requirements.

Comment: `aggressive-resize` predates the other stuff here and the intent is that when tmux is automatically sizing a window, it only checks the size of a session the window is linked to if the window is the current window. It is aggressive because this meant that if you have the same window linked to multiple sessions, it will be resized more often with the option on than with it off (because with it on it could be resized when it becomes the current window). In practice I am not sure aggressive-resize matters anymore and we should probably just make having it on the default.

Answer (score 0):

I have not yet figured out how to do this automatically.
But if you use `xterm`,
you can do this manually:

1. detach from the `tmux` session,
2. type `resize` into your terminal and run it,
3. return to your session and the window should be resized.